# How to bind an input field in jsp to a property in a list

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to bind an object with a list as its property to input fields in jsp. Here is my jsp code

```
        <form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post"
        modelAttribute="codingPropertiesModel" action="<%=updateCodingPropertiesURL%>">
            <c:set var="counter" value="0"></c:set>
            <c:forEach items="${codingPropertiesModel.codingList}" var="coding" varStatus="status">
                <tr>

                    <td>${counter + 1}</td>

                    <td>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input type="text"
                            path="codingList[${status.index}].codeInLevel" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors path="codingList[${status.index}].codeInLevel" class="control-label" />
                    </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}"></c:set>
            </c:forEach>
```

And the object is created from the following classes:

```
public class CodingProperties {

private UUID id;
private Language language;
private CompanyType companyType;
private List<CodingModel> codingList;
    // ....
    /**
     * @return the codingSet
     */
    public List<CodingModel> getCodingList() {
        return codingList;
    }
    /**
     * @param codingSet the codingSet to set
     */
    public void setCodingList(List<CodingModel> codingSet) {
        this.codingList = codingSet;
    }
    // ....
}
```

And

```
public class CodingModel {
    private String codeInLevel;
    /**
    * @return the codeInLevel
    */
    public String getCodeInLevel() {
        return codeInLevel;
    }
    /**
    * @param codeInLevel the codeInLevel to set
    */
    public void setCodeInLevel(String codeInLevel) {
        this.codeInLevel = codeInLevel;
    }
```

But when I run the code and it whats to show results, an error is occurred:

```
                    <td>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input type="text"
path="codingList[${status.index}].codeInLevel" class="form-control" />
                        <form:errors     path="codingList[${status.index}].codeInLevel" class="control-label" />
                    </div>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'codingList[0].codeInLevel' of bean class [base.models.template.CodingProperties]: Bean property 'codingList[0].codeInLevel' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:619)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:610)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.JSP.accounting.base.coding.updateCodingProperties_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(updateCodingProperties_jsp.java:1180)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.JSP.accounting.base.coding.updateCodingProperties_jsp._jspService(updateCodingProperties_jsp.java:349)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Several questions like this is answered, but none of them is solved my problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use coding.codeInLevel?

Comment: Yes. It gets error `Invalid property 'coding' of bean class [base.models.template.CodingProperties]`

Comment: I think you should use a wrapper because you're using a forEach inside form.